# Como mostrar ecuaciones matematicas en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

Estoy investigando como utilizar MathJax y AlgebraJS, y tengo el siguiente codigo, pero me marca error y no corre, alguien sabe como se utilizan estas herramientas con React? Mi intencion es solo mostrarlas en la pantalla, no busco resolver calculos de ningun tipo, de momento.

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import MathJax from 'react-mathjax2'
        const ascii = 'U = 1/(R_(si) + sum_(i=1)^n(s_n/lambda_n) + R_(se))'
        const content = `This can be dynamic text (e.g. user-entered) text with ascii math embedded in $$ symbols like $$${ascii}$$`
class Ecuaciones extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(

        module.exports = () => {
            return (
                <div align="center">
                <br />
                <br />
                <Typography><h1>Compendio de Ecuaciones de Ciencia e Ingenieria</h1></Typography>
                <MathJax.Context
                    input='ascii'
                    onLoad={ () => console.log("Loaded MathJax script!") }
                    onError={ (MathJax, error) => {
                        console.warn(error);
                        console.log("Encountered a MathJax error, re-attempting a typeset!");
                        MathJax.Hub.Queue(
                          MathJax.Hub.Typeset()
                        );
                    } }
                    script="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML"
                    options={ {
                        asciimath2jax: {
                             useMathMLspacing: true,
                             delimiters: [["$$","$$"]],
                             preview: "none",
                        }
                    } }
                >
                    <MathJax.Text text={ content }/>
                </MathJax.Context>
                </div>
            );
        }
        );
    }
}
export default Ecuaciones;
```

Les agradezco, recien estoy aprendiendo React, y me sorprende el mundo de cosas que hay por aprender.

Comment: debes instalar mathjax como un paquete npm no como una referencia. Aqui las instrucciones [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax]

Comment: Ya lo instale de hecho, use el comando de npm en la consola, el problema creo que esta en el codigo

Comment: De hecho, utilice el codigo y el npm de este git: https://github.com/wko27/react-mathjax

Comment: Con este comando para instalar: npm install react-mathjax2 --save

Comment: Entonces alguien sabe? O conocen de alguna web donde pueda aprender?